# How to calculate the sum of dice rolls efficiently?

Tags: python, algorithm, math

The following code:

```
import random
def roll(num_dice,num_faces):
    return sum([random.randint(1,num_faces) for x in range(num_dice)])
```

does randomly generate the sum of `num_dice` `num_faces`-faced dice, but it is slow (`O(N)`) for large numbers of dice.

What is a more efficient way to calculate this in python?

Comment: How large are you talking about? Are you hitting memory limits? If so, then using a generator expression would help, or any other approach that doesnt materialize a full list. Otherwise, try `numpy`. But I don't think you can escape linear time complexity here.

Comment: If you're rolling so many dice that linear time is a problem, it's probably time to use an approximation.

Comment: If you're doing repeated trials, you can precompute so that each trial is better than linear time. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate it in `O(1)` have a look at this function:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html

if you calculate

```
np.random.multinomial(num_dices,[1/float(num_faces)]*num_faces)
```

the execution time depends only from num_faces, not from num_dices

Comment: That takes time linear in the number of dice too. It's faster because Cython, but still linear in the number of dice.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I misread the `numpy.random.multinomial` source - the implementation uses a different algorithm than the one I mistook it for. The runtime is indeed proportional to the number of faces, not the number of dice.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it much faster, if you use the multinominal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
def roll_np(num_dice,num_faces):
    return sum((np.array(range(num_faces))+1)*np.random.multinomial(num_dice,[1/float(num_faces)]*num_faces))
```

The runtime of this implemetion is independent from `num_dice`.
I have tested it:

```
from time import time
t=time();roll_np(10000,6);print(time()-t)
```

> 34997
>
> 0.0005793571472167969

```
t=time();roll_np(10000,6);print(time()-t)
```

> 34938
>
> 0.0005676746368408203

```
t=time();roll_np(10000000,6);print(time()-t)
```

> 34996283
>
> 0.0006160736083984375

```
t=time();roll_np(10000000,6);print(time()-t)
```

> 34996047
>
> 0.000567913055419921